# Rank $2$ Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm on a quest for some rank $2$ elliptic curves. My question is actually twofold:

- Is there a way to easily construct a curve with this property?
- Is there a database of elliptic curves with given rank?

I know Cremona has an extensive list of curves, but it seems like access to his tables require Linux. Am I wrong on this? References on constructing curves to have a certain rank is welcome, as are Pari/GP and Sage programs that anyone may have.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.lmfdb.org/?

Comment: @Sanchez Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Sage Notebook](http://www.sagenb.org/) to evaluate Sage code online.

For example:

```
    elliptic_curves.rank(n=5, rank=2, tors=0, labels=false)
```

With output:

> Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2 - 2*x over Rational
>   Field
>
> Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y = x^3 + 1 over Rational
>   Field
>
> Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y = x^3 - x^2 - 4*x + 4 over
>   Rational Field
>
> Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y + y = x^3 + x^2 -
>   15*x + 16 over Rational Field
>
> Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + y = x^3 +
>   x^2 - 4*x + 2 over Rational Field

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be something from Sage.

Answer (score 5):

Accessing Cremona's tables does not need Linux:

- You can access [the database directly here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/). For instance, data for the curves of conductors between 1 and 9999 [can be found here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/ftp/data/allcurves.00000-09999.gz).
- But nowadays there is a much better interface, [the LMFDB database](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q)! You can find $100$ elliptic curves of rank $2$ just by [searching the database](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q?conductor=&jinv=&rank=2&torsion=&torsion_structure=&sha_an=&optimal=&count=100).

Here is the first example with rank $2$ in the database: [0, 1, 1, -2, 0], i.e.,
$$E: y^2 +y=x^3+x^2-2x.$$