# Elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with two distinct non-torsion points $P$ and $Q$ such that $nP \neq mQ$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

We know an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ can have at most finite number of torsion points. The torsion group for $E$, $E_{tors}$ is either $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $1 \leq n \leq 10$ or $n = 12,$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $2 \leq n \leq 4.$  I am looking for example of an elliptic curve $E$ with two non-torsion points $P$ and $Q$ such that $nP \neq mQ$ for  $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}.$ In other words we must have $<P> \cap <Q> = \{O\},$ where $O$ is the point at infinity.

Comment: So you are looking for an elliptic curve of rank greater than $1$?

Comment: The LMFDB has many examples. Here's one where $P$ and $Q$ have integral coordinates: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/664/a/1.

Comment: The statement you make is false. An elliptic curve over any algebraically closed field has infinitely many torsion points... you need to include some hypotheses on the base field (since you are quoting Mazur's theorem i guess you want $K = \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_elliptic_curve) for a general discussion on elliptic curves of high rank.

If you want the rank to be exactly 2 you can consult Cremona's tables. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367718/rank-2-elliptic-curves) is a discussion on Math Stackexchange with links included.